# How to show views from plugins, loaded dynamically via Autofac?

Tags: c#, autofac

I have several independent libraries with some exporting main views. 
There is a Shell with TabControl and want to load all views into separate tabs. 
I can register all types from this plugins but do not know how to show all this main views.
For example, I have registered 5 Views from 5 plugins, but how to pass it to ShellView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an interface

```
public interface ITabView {
}
```

that all views implement

```
public class MyFirstView : UserControl, ITabView
{
  ....
}
```

and you register them by something like

```
builder.RegisterType<MyFirstView>().As<ITabView>();
builder.RegisterType<MySecondView>().As<ITabView>();
```

then you can access them all (even if they're registered in different assemblies) by injecting a generic IEnumerable into the constructor of the ShellView like

```
public ShellView(IEnumerable<ITabView> tabViews)
{
  foreach (var view in tabViews)
  {
    ... Create a tab for each view, make the tab the parent of the view
    ... and add the tab to the TabControl
  }
}
```